# "Go to source" math envinroments – TeXstudio

Tags: math-mode, texstudio, viewers

When I `Ctrl+Click` on an equation that is inside a math environment(`align`, `gather`) at texstudio's viewer, it jump to the `\end{...}`, but the the actual equation I've clicked.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Does other LaTeX editors have finer jumping destinations? The "Go to source/Go to PDF" uses auxiliary file produced by `synctex` program. That info might not be very accurate.

Comment: ams alignments grab the entire alignment and do a pass measuring and then does a second pass that actually typesets. I doubt tex or synctex have the information about what part of the environment generates which line, you see a similar thin if you have an error tex will report it as coming from `\end{align}`

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ overleaf provides such an access, for example. You can double click a single character and it jumps straight to it.

Comment: @antshar I cannot reproduce what you said about overleaf. (I am free user of overleaf.) With equation `\begin{align}
  a &= b \\
  c &= d \\ 
  e &= f \\ 
\end{align}`, select "a &= b" and click "Go to code location in PDF", the whole three-line equation is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I found that eqnarray would allow the synctex to work. I later found that the package eqnarray provides a command equationarray that would resolve some issues. I just do

```
\begin{equationarray}{rl}
 a &= b
\end{equationarray}
```

You can adjust the spacing around = with `\arraycolsep 0.1em`. Note that `equationarray` is not as good as `align` for various aspects, but I am personally willing to take this tradeoff.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).